# Prevent metro apps which have to maintain remote connections from closing when backgrounded

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, microsoft-surface

How can I prevent Windows from closing/hibernating/sleeping/etc... backgrounded Metro applications?

Basically, I have a Surface 2 (the ARM one), and I often have two applications open. A text editor, and a SSH session. I make changes to a script file in the text editor, and run the changed file on a remote server via the SSH session.

Fairly often, I'll switch from the SSH session to the text-editor, make some changes to a file, and when I switch back to the SSH session to execute the changed file, windows will have closed the application, making me have to go through the login process again.

This gets *extremely* annoying very quickly.

How can I force windows to NEVER close specific metro applications, even if it thinks it should?

---

<sub>I'm not low on RAM (task manager generally shows ~50% utilization). I cannot install more, as the tablet is non-upgradeable. Besides, even if there was memory pressure, that's what swap is for.</sub>

<sub>I cannot use a non-metro SSH client, as this is the ARM Surface, which will not run non-metro applications.</sub>

Comment: Well, have the time when I switch, it terminates my session. What else could cause it? It may be "sleeping" the app, rather then closing it, but that's just a terminological difference. If the application in question no longer gets CPU cycles, it's closed.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have trouble believing that, as it would be a spectacularly stupid client design decision if it were true.

Comment: Anyways, doing research, it appears windows *does indeed shut down* background applications, except for specific async callback functions (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/16/being-productive-when-your-app-is-offscreen.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)).

Comment: Sure;  You know more then I do clear;  Good Luck!

Comment: @Ramhound - If that's how I came across, I apologize. I'm bad at conveying things like nuance online.

Comment: It might seem a minor thing to argue that minimizing a Modern UI application is not closing it, but if you hit the close button even on Windows 10, it doesn't actually kill the process.  You can set it up like that but by default it does not END/KILL the process.  There is literal meaning in words.  Terminological  is important.

Answer (score 1):

The command line tool [PLMDebug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj680085(v=vs.85).aspx), which is part of the Debugging Tools in the [Windows SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891), can be used to exempt an app from the Process Lifetime Management (PLM) policies.  When put into debug mode, an app will not be  automatically suspended.

Usage:

```
plmdebug /enableDebug <PackageFullName> [OptionalDebuggerCommandLine]
```